# How to show some of category in wordpress

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer, categories

I listed all category in front page with **get_categories()** function 
But i dont want show all category in output
For example i dont want show catgegory with id=25
How to should i do that?

This is my code

```
<?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id) ?>" class="post-cats-item">
        <div class="post-cats-thumbnail">
            <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>"/>
            <div class="post-cats-cover"></div>
            <h3 class="post-cats-name"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h3>
        </div>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
$args = array(  
    'hide_empty'               => 1,    
    'exclude'                  =>array(1,2,3) // desire id
); 

$categories = get_categories($args );
```

Hope it will help!